# Is it possible to pass just one parameter for this generic extension method?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

```
 //In a Static class ,extension implementation
 public static IQueryable<T2> ToDTO<T, T2>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        return source.To<T2>();
    }

//Usage
var result = personType1Queryable.ToDTO< personType1, personType2>();
```

In above code as you see its an extension. It converts one type to another. So first **this** referenced object is personType1Queryable typed **IQueryable < personType1 >** I just want to call this function like this;

```
personType1Queryable.ToDTO<personType2>();
```

I just want to pass just destination type. Because **this** referenced object already passed. But compiler doesn't accept this why? For Where < T > extension in Linq it works.
For me why not?

EDIT: I applied Eren's answer. But it seems still something missing.

```
  //works
    public static IQueryable<T2> ToDTO<T,T2>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Project().To<T2>();
    }

  //gives object reference error. Shown below!
    public static IQueryable<T> ToDTO<T>(this IQueryable<object> source)
    {
        return source.Project().To<T>();
    }
```

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yh6H.png

Comment: What's the compiler error.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/partial-type-inference-in-net.html

Comment: @EliGassert: No overload has 1 generic parameter.

Comment: ah yes I see what you're comment is referring to now. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>` is covariant in `T`, so depending on what you need in the `To<T>` extension, you might get away with this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ToDTO<T>(this IQueryable<object> source)
{
    return source.To<T>();
}
```

Note that this will only work if the type parameter of the original `IQueryable<T>` (e.g. `personType1`) is a *reference type*. Otherwise, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: For value types the extension does not appear :)

Answer (score 0):

`Where` is defined as

`public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)`

As you can see it uses only one generic parameter, that's why it 'works' when you provide one.
Your method is defined with two parameters.

Comment: For where you do not need to pass <TSource> AFAIK you can query by this way Where(predicate). It knows TSource from this refereced IEnumerable<TSource>. And I also do not want to pass this parameter's type again.

Comment: Yes, but OP is saying that one of the two types, `T`, can be inferred from the argument. They want to pass just the second explicitly.